# Pythonic way to iterate over bits of integer

Tags: python, binary, iterator

Let's `a=109` or `1101101` in binary. How do I iterate over bits of this number, eg: `[64, 32, 8, 4, 1]`

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators should be enough

Comment: If you're looking for converting numbers you can use `bin(109)` or `int('1101101', 2)`.

Comment: `map(lambda x: int(x), bin(NUMBER)[2:])`.  But this solution is probably too easy and unpythonic. ;)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There's a trick for just getting the 1's out of the binary representation without having to iterate over all the intervening 0's:

```
def bits(n):
    while n:
        b = n & (~n+1)
        yield b
        n ^= b


>>> for b in bits(109):
    print(b)


1
4
8
32
64
```

Comment: Nice one. Made me do some timings.

Comment: really neat, can't help to amaze

Comment: Small explanation of the method: https://lemire.me/blog/2018/02/21/iterating-over-set-bits-quickly/

Comment: any way to yield those indicies in reverse (largest to smallest)?

Comment: @Peabrain I've been using this code for a short-while and came across the same need. Need to start iterating the bits in reverse. Easy enough if you don't care about performance but ideally there should be an inverse of this method.

Comment: This is especially efficient if you have a lot of cases where most of the bits are 0, but just a few are 1.  Winston's solution might be better if you expect a lot of the bits to be 1, and if you are going for readability.
I also found that this breaks if you give it a negative number, so you might want to add `n = abs(n)` at the beginning, or just make sure inputs are unsigned.

Answer (score 14):

My approach:

```
def bits(number):
    bit = 1
    while number >= bit:
       if number & bit:
           yield bit
       bit <<= 1
```

I don't think there is a builtin function for it.

I also wonder if there isn't a better approach to whatever you are doing. There's a good chance you don't really want to iterate over the bits like this. They may be a much better way.

Out of curiosity I ran some timing on the methods posted here, my results:

```
Winston 2.35238099098
F.J. 6.21106815338
F.J. (2) 5.21456193924
Sven 2.90593099594
Duncan 2.33568000793
freegnu 4.67035484314
```

F.J. converts to a string, I'm guessing that hurts his performance. The various optimisation attempts help, but not enough Sven produces the reverse of everybody else, which might be an advantage if you really needed that. Duncan's approach wins speedwise (just barely)

Again with 340282366920938463463374607431768211457 instead of 109:

```
Winston 44.5073108673
F.J. 74.7332041264
Sven 47.6416211128
Duncan 2.58612513542
```

Nice, Duncan! It should be noted that this is pretty much the best case for Duncan's method, so it won't always have this dramatic an advantage.

Comment: That loop condition should probably be `number >= bit`.

Comment: how do the times work out for other values, e.g. for a=340282366920938463463374607431768211457 ?

Comment: Can you compare the timings of my improvement on @F J's version.

Comment: I don't think Duncan's has a worst case scenario. Nice maths @Duncan.

Comment: @freegnu,Duncan's is faster for binary numbers with lots of zeros. Its probably always gonna be the fastest method, but it won't always be as fast as my second test suggests since the number there is something like: 1000000000000000000000000001

Comment: more like 0b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 , so the advantage of Duncan's answer (quite an old C trick, indeed) is quite exaggerated :)

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> [2**i for i, v in enumerate(bin(109)[:1:-1]) if int(v)]
[1, 4, 8, 32, 64]
```

Obviously the order is reversed here, you could either just use this or reverse the result:

```
>>> [2**i for i, v in enumerate(bin(109)[:1:-1]) if int(v)][::-1]
[64, 32, 8, 4, 1]
```

**edit:** Here is a slightly longer version that should be more efficient:

```
from itertools import takewhile, count
[p for p in takewhile(lambda x: x <= 109, (2**i for i in count())) if p & 109]
```

Comment: The string conversion is faster than the iterator version on the worst case scenario 340282366920938463463374607431768211457 and maybe anything over a certain size. I changed your if int() test into a string test =='1' to speed things up. @Duncan's still beats it handily tho.

Answer (score 4):

S.O. won't let me put this as a comment, but here's a line-by-line example of how [Duncan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107660/duncan) solution works. Hopefully this clarifies what's happening.

**Let's use the decimal number 109 as an example**:

```
# 109 is .............. 0110 1101
# ~109 is -110 which is 1001 0010   NOTE: It's -110 instead of -109 because of 1's compliment
# ~109+1 is -109....... 1001 0011
# 109 AND ~109 is...... 0000 0001 = 1  <---- 1st value yielded by the generator
# 109 XOR 1 is......... 0110 1100 = n = 108

# 108.................. 0110 1100
# ~108+1= -108......... 1001 0100
# 108 AND -108......... 0000 0100 = 4  <---- 2nd value yielded by the generator
# 108 XOR 4............ 0110 1000 = n = 104

# 104.................. 0110 1000
# ~104+1............... 1001 1000
# 104 AND -104......... 0000 1000 = 8  <---- 3rd value yielded by the generator
# 104 XOR 8............ 0110 0000 = n = 96

# 96................... 0110 0000
# ~96+1................ 1010 0000
# 96 AND -96........... 0010 0000 = 32 <---- 4th value yielded by the generator
# 96 XOR 32............ 0100 0000 = n = 64

# 64................... 0100 0000
# ~64+1................ 1100 0000
# 64 AND -64........... 0100 0000 = 64 <---- 5th value yielded by the generator
# 64 XOR 64............ 0000 0000 = n = 0; thus, the while loop terminates.
```

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.7:

```
def binary_decomposition(x):
    p = 2 ** (int(x).bit_length() - 1)
    while p:
        if p & x:
            yield p
        p //= 2
```

Example:

```
>>> list(binary_decomposition(109))
[64, 32, 8, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency of F.J.'s answer can be dramatically improved.

```
from itertools import count,takewhile
[2**i for i in takewhile(lambda x:109>2**x,count()) if 109&2**i][::-1]
```

I like one liners :)

I did a quick timeit.Timer.timeit() against this and @Duncan. Duncan still wins but not the one liner is at least in the same class.

```
from timeit import Timer
duncan="""\
def bits(n):
 while n:
  b=n&(~n+1)
  yield b
  n^=b
"""
Duncan=Timer('list(bits(109))[::-1]',duncan)
Duncan.timeit()
4.3226630687713623
freegnu=Timer('[2**i for i in takewhile(lambda x:109>2**x,count()) if 109&2**i][::-1]','from itertools import count,takewhile')
freegnu.timeit()
5.2898638248443604
```

Answer (score 0):

Example one-line solution:

```
[1 << bit for bit in xrange(bitfield.bit_length()) if bitfield & (1 << bit)]
```

Or:

```
[bit for bit in (1 << n for n in xrange(bitfield.bit_length())) if bitfield & bit]
```

Notes:

- use range in Python 3
- think about checking bitfield is >= 0